# Конфигурация оборудования и определение наличия расширенной памяти

Tags: c

Добрый вечер всем :)
Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу определить наличие расширенной памяти и конфигурацию оборудования(это вообще не понимааю как). Или вообще не существует таких функций? Если кто-нибудь знает,как реализовать эти функции на СИ, помогите,пожалуйста.

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/753019/23044

Comment: там так и не было ответа о конфигурации) и расширенной памяти) эти все ссылки уже пересмотрела 10500 раз:(

Comment: Это вопрос про допотопные технологии примерно 20-летней давности...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, вопрос какой есть) Задание в универе дали, преподаватель сказал что до нас такое уже делали, поэтому проблем у нас возникнуть не должно) В примере решения задания вообще были "dos.h" и"sysp.h".  Расширенную память уже нашла как определить, да и конфигурацию ту же( через три другие функции), но вот одну функцию все же не могу на СИ реализовать - GetKeyboardType. Если знаете как, буду очень признательна за помощь)

Comment: отсутствие ответа это не повод вопрос-дубликат сразу задавать. В общем случае лучше больше подробностей добавить в оригинальный вопрос. К примеру, если вы напишите что вас только dos интересует, то это резко поясняет что вы понимаете под "расширенной памятью" и сужает возможные решения. Я бы не стал давать ответ, который на Linux или Windows работает тогда. Если вы ещё явно упомяните, что вы конкретно под "конфигурацией оборудования" понимаете , то вопрос хуже не станет. Ни dos.h ни sysp.h не являются частью стандартного Си. Если вам их необходимо использовать, явно *в вопросе* их упомяните.

Comment: @jfs, извините. Конкретно ничего не могла объяснить потому что сама не понимала, было задание передо мной, как реализовать - не знала, думала может подскажет кто. Но потратив часов 10, все таки написала то что хотела)

Comment: если думаете что нашли решение, то опубликуйте как свой ответ — это [явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)