# C# Как достать информацию об устройствах компьютера не используя WMI

Tags: c#, winapi, железо

Как достать информацию о устройствах компьютера,
используя "*Kernel32.dll*"

Смог узнать серийный номер жесткого диска, модель и объем жесткого, используя этот код.

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int DeviceIoControl(
            int hDevice,
            int dwIoControlCode,
            [In(), Out()] SENDCMDINPARAMS lpInBuffer,
            int lpInBufferSize,
            [In(), Out()] SENDCMDOUTPARAMS lpOutBuffer,
            int lpOutBufferSize,
            ref int lpBytesReturned,
            int lpOverlapped
        );
```

Где информация о процессоре, материнке, операционке?
Искал в PInvoke.net

Comment: В текущей формулировке вопрос слишком общий, так как содержит сразу три вопроса. Упоминание конкретной kernel32.dll значительно сокращает количество возможных ответов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, некоторую информацию можно получить без всякого P/Invoke.

Класс *Environment*:

```
Console.WriteLine("OS version: " + Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Processor count: " + Environment.ProcessorCount.ToString());
```

Ветка реестра *HKLM\Hardware*:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

//...

object result = Registry.GetValue(
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0", 
"ProcessorNameString",  "");

if (result != null) Console.WriteLine("Processor name: " + (result).ToString());

result = Registry.GetValue(
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0",
"~MHz", 0);

if (result != null) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processor frequency: " + ((int)result).ToString()+" MHz");
}

result = Registry.GetValue(
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS"
, "BaseBoardManufacturer", "");

if (result != null) Console.WriteLine("Motherboard vendor: " + (result).ToString());

result = Registry.GetValue(
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS"
, "BaseBoardProduct", 0);

if (result != null) Console.WriteLine("Motherboard name: " + (result).ToString());
```

---

Но основная часть информации об устройствах находится в таблице SMBIOS, которую можно получить функцией [GetSystemFirmwareTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724379(v=vs.85).aspx) (действительно, из kernel32.dll):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetSystemFirmwareTable(
    uint FirmwareTableProviderSignature,
    uint FirmwareTableID,
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pFirmwareTableBuffer,
    uint BufferSize);

// ...

byte[] arr = new byte[5000];                
uint sig = 0x52534D42;//RSMB

uint res = GetSystemFirmwareTable(sig, 0, arr, 5000);
if (res == 0 || res > 5000) 
{
      throw new ApplicationException("GetSystemFirmwareTable failed");
}
```

Структура таблицы SMBIOS описана в спецификации: https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios

Пример извлечения сведений об оборудовании на языке C можно найти [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753935/240512). Также, [здесь](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/blob/da432ef07cf125c019afd3a27f447da428404611/Hardware/SMBIOS.cs) есть код парсера SMBIOS на C#, под лицензией MPL.