# Как получить информацию только по дискретным видеокартам?

Tags: c#, wmi

Мне нужно получить совсем базовые вещи(название, pnpdeviceid, возможно кол-во памяти и все) Ранее использовал WMI(не нашел аналог из MSFT) и есть следующий код, но он выводил и встроенные видеокарты тоже.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");
foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item["Name"]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"DeviceId: {item["PnpDeviceId"]}");
}
```

Сейчас использую библиотеку https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor и она выводит только дискретные видеокарты, но почему-то создает .sys файл, который часто не удаляемый даже при завершении процесса.

Нашел такое([C# Как достать информацию об устройствах компьютера не используя WMI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778618/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-wmi)), но это слишком. Возможно есть что-то попроще?

Comment: такой запрос подойдет? `ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController WHERE AdapterRAM > 0 AND NOT VideoProcessor LIKE '%Software%'")` 
Условие AdapterRAM > 0 отфильтровывает видеокарты с нулевым объемом памяти, а условие NOT VideoProcessor LIKE '%Software%' исключает видеокарты, которые используют программное эмулирование

Comment: @Ruslan работает! Спасибо. Ответ оформите?  И еще как вы узнали про VideoProcessor и LIKE "Software"? В описании Win32_VideoController и его базовых классах нет перечисления какие могут быть варианты начала строки VideoProcessor.

Comment: @Ruslan все-таки не всегда работает. На 10100 корректно отработал. 12400 вывел uhd730 и AdapterRam > 0 было. Пока что не понял почему так(

Comment: "12400 вывел uhd730", а если на этом ядре дернуть "SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController" - то какой ответ будет? интересует не да/нет, а полный вывод (сделай лог в теримнал результат переменной `var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");`)

Comment: в теории `where AdapterRAM > 0` - должно выдавать именно дискретные, хочется все же посмотреть, что лежит в 12400 общий select

Comment: "И еще как вы узнали про VideoProcessor и LIKE "Software"" - дернул у себя локально, убрал лишнее из ответов, обычный sql

Comment: @Ruslan вот запрос `SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController` https://pastebin.com/raw/DStrwBTa

Comment: pastebin в рф не доступен (ну или только у меня)

Comment: @Ruslan у меня в рф доступен. Перезалил https://gist.github.com/Lapish/f15f4dcbcd3ecdb5d82551ba4e6036bd